# can anyone tell me How much it takes to install ubuntu 12.04 from windows installer?

Tags: 12.04

can anyone tell me 
How much it takes to install ubuntu 12.04 from windows installer?

Comment: How much what? Potatoes?

Comment: Please elaborate on what "how much it takes" means? Do you want to know the total amount of bits?

Comment: Maybe this [installation guide](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-desktop-long-term-support) gives you an impression what "it takes".

Answer (score 0):

If you have kept the wubi.exe and the iso file in same folder. Then:

Installing the software: max. 5 minutes;
Installing the system: 30 min. approx.

Try to keep hardisk space of at least 10 GB for smooth run